# How can I fix these constraints so the text appears to the right of the image in my UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am having issues with my constraints on my UITableViewCells and I can't seem to figure out how to fix these constraints that I've coded. I want the text to stretch across the cell and start to right of the image on the far left side. I just want the text centered in the cell if possible but I am unsure of how to accomplish this goal. As of right now, I have the width set to the height of the text but if you're able to help guide me so the text is adjacent to the image on the left side, that would be greatly appreciated. I have also attached a picture below of the current setup (which you will agree looks quite ugly)

**Heres the code:**

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(mainImageView)
    self.addSubview(messageView)

    mainImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    mainImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    mainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    messageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    messageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkxYO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to set

> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

for each component before add constraints.

after that here you set imageview top,bottom & height,width constraints also.each will conflict with other.you have to use only one set of them.either top,bottom or height,width.

using top,bottom constraints is not recommended.it makes image stretchy sometimes.better using width height constraints and center your image to center Y.

```
    mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor,constant:16).isActive = true
    mainImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    mainImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    mainImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    messageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    messageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    messageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    messageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

you can center your text in messageview using textAlignment

[image: More info]

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed the problem I really appreciate the help